# No internet connectivity after uninstalling VPN in win10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, vpn, internet-connection

A barracuda VPN client was installed in my windows 10 machine which was not working. I simply uninstalled the VPN and restarted my machine as required. Since the next boot my windows can't access internet through either wifi or Ethernet port. It can connect to the wifi hotspot though but always says "No internet". Same goes for ethernet port too.

I am sure that my wifi is working because I'm using my mobile to ask this question here that is using the same hotspot.

Please help. The only way left at this moment is to reinstall the OS which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

#### Reinitialise the network states

Run the following commands in a `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh winsock reset catalog
  ```
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh int ip reset reset.log
  ```
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh advfirewall reset
  ```
- Flush DNS resolver cache :

  ```
  ipconfig /flushdns
  ```
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  ```
  ipconfig /registerdns
  ```
- Flush routing table:

  ```
  route /f
  ```

  (reboot required)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already found some of those steps you mentioned in microsoft forum and tried them. Even then I tried your steps in same order again (http://pastebin.com/5jLCSj9x). But no luck. I couldn't wait more so I reinstalled my system. However, the original problem is still a mystery to me. Will get back here again, if I come across the situation again or find any solution for this. Thanks again for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and I tried almost everything I found on varoius forums but nothing really worked. At last I did this (on Windows 10 20H2) and it solved my problem in 5 minutes:

1. Open Start and search "Network reset".
2. Click it and a settings page will open.
3. Click "Reset now".
4. A dialog box will open which says that the pc would restart in 5 minutes.

Your problem will be solved. But remember any saved Wi-Fi password will be also deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me when I encountered this problem. Instead of doing a bunch of resets, you can try going to the Start menu in windows and then going to Run. Type in inetcpl.cpl. Then go to connections and go to Lan settings. Make sure that proxy server is unchecked and make sure that Automatically detect settings is checked. Then press ok or apply and it should fix your internet.