# Windows 10 ethernet stops working until disabled and re-enabled

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers, ethernet, wired-networking

I'm experiencing a frustrating issue with my Ethernet connection on my laptop, Acer Aspire V3-571.

The network seems to stop working, randomly from the best of my knowledge. It then won't function again until I disable the adaptor and re-enable it through "Network connections". Can't access any websites or the LAN machines that are connected.

Right now I have a fresh installation of Windows 10, which I assume will be using a Microsoft Ethernet driver. However I did have the same issue prior to the clean Windows 10 installation. I actually re-installed Windows 10 because I thought it would fix the issue.

Is there something I should try when the network next drops in order to help figure out if this is a driver issue or hardware issue?

Here is an image of the event viewer:

[image: Event Viewer]

The k57nd60a events are me disabling and re-enabling the adapter to fix the issue. I guess DisributedCOM might be unrelated, however the DNS errors are because the network has gone. There doesn't appear to be any other errors in the event viewer that are related.

K57ND60A appears to be a Broadcom network adapter, I had tried various Broadcom drivers before re-installing Windows 10, non of which seemed to resolve the issue.

I am running on 'High Performance' power plan too, which again doesn't appear to have helped.

Any advice is most welcome as it's surprising how annoying this issue is!

**Update 1**
Just happened again, took down some images for various info/pings.
I disable the adapter and re-enable and it's now working correctly.

[image: Ping attempts]

Comment: Do you have other devices connected through this LAN? we can't rule out that its something that happens at the router's end. Disabling and Reenabling the network card refreshes the IP adress. Both Wired and Wireless are fine. So you could test this with a mobile phone too.

Comment: Also, when it happens, can you still ping the router? What is your IP Address at the moment of the malfunction?

Comment: Do you get the same IP Address after re-enabling the Ethernet connection?

Comment: Try [Reinitialising the network states](https://superuser.com/a/1095736/337631)

Comment: The IP of the laptop I am using is set via the office DHCP to always get the same IP address. Also when it happens I do have an IP address assigned still from what I can see using 'ipconfig /all'
I will try your suggestion @DavidPostill

Comment: @LPChip I can't ping the router when the malfunction happens. I can ping 127.0.0.1 I believe, but that is all.

Comment: Are there other devices in your network, and do they still work normally when it happens?

Comment: @LPChip there are several other devices that all work okay, even when my laptop is having the issue. I feel the problem is related to the laptop I am using.
I have used Davids information from above, and so far I have not received any further disconnects, but I will have to run for longer to be sure if the problem is cured or not!

Comment: Given that the problem exists even after a windows install, makes me think that DavidPostill's solution won't work. I would look into a hardware problem which would be a faulty network card, problems with the network cable or problems with the router.

Comment: @LPChip I suspect you are right as it just happened again! I have added details. I will have to look at the hardware ( network card ) I guess I have already swapped the cable and no other devices on the network seem to be affected.